# Design Decision - WCF Service or Shared Class Library (DLL)

Tags: wcf, dll

I am presently designing a message queue system that will be used by various applications and am having a difficult time trying to decide whether to use WCF to provide the services or use a shared class library (DLL) and deploy the DLL with the clients.

For some additional information:

•   The queue is stored in a SQL database.

•   We expect to have approximately 3-7 different applications/clients using this message queue system.

•   The clients/applications may or may not run all on one machine.

•   We do not expect a heavy load of messages being queued on a daily basis (approx 1000-10000 per day (gross estimates btw))

•   Somewhat “mission critical” – several clients/applications cannot do its job if this service is unavailable.

•   Everything operates within the corporate network – no access to Internet required.

I have given some though to the pros and cons for each decision:

**WCF Service**

**Pros:**

•   Can update the logic in the Queue system without having to update the clients

•   Room for scalability – but most likely not going to be an issue.

**Cons:**

•   More difficult to diagnose/debug

•   More effort required when deploying

•   Queue System unavailable if the service is down (unless we cluster/farm)

**Shared Class Library (DLL)**

**Pros:**

•   Easier to debug

•   Easier development efforts

•   Only have to ensure that the DB is available – no dependence on another service/machine.

**Cons:**

•   Deployment headaches when we make updates to the DLL – we may forget to update all the applications that depend on the DLL.

If anyone can provide more arguments for a solution – that would be helpful! If you have an opinion to what you believe is the best direction, please do tell! I’ll appreciate any input that will help make me a decision.

Thanks for your time,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both:

- Implement a class library that encapsulates all the functionality you wish to expose. Consumers that wish that level of control can reference the library directly.
- Develop a WCF service that only acts as a Remote Facade for the class library. It would only expose and translate the class library into DTOs/messages, and contain no logic in itself.

In other words, the class library is your Domain Model, and the service is just a thin Facade in front of that model. That's the way any WCF service should be developed in any case.

---

That said, I you *must* choose one or the other, I'll try to add my own thought to yours (which I find most reaonable).

One disadvantage of WCF that you forgot is that it does add some processing overhead because it must serialize and deserialze messages.

Even so, selecting the best model is not only about counting the number of bullets in each pro/con section, as each bullet has different weights.

Without knowing your exact situation and requirements, I would still consider the deployment/versioning issue that relates to direct use of a class library to be a very strong argument against that strategy.

A web service interface will allow you to vary service and each client independently of each other as long as the contract remains stable. That could also be made possible with a class library, but is more difficult.

An interoperable web service interface also gives you a better ability to grow and respond to new business opportunities, as the clients are not constrained to .NET applications. You may have only .NET applications today, but are you sure it will stay that way forever?

If, on the other hand, you decide to go the class library route, make sure to have each client consume abstract base classes, because that will provide you with the most flexible options of changing the implementation without breaking existing clients.

Given the information you provided, I don't think there's a clear-cut winner here. I lean slightly towards WCF despite the added complexity, because I consider the flexibility it provides gives you better options for responding to unforseen changes.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That's typically how I develop my WCF services however in our case, we want all clients either use the DLL or WCF (both is a maintenance headache in our opinion). We are wondering if we should reference a shared DLL or a shared web service. If in the future we realize we may need WCF, then a shared DLL would be interfaced with a "remote facade" and all clients would be updated to use the WCF service.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've expanded on my answer to better address that dimension of your question (although I have no clear answer).

Comment: @Mark: excellent write up, and I would concur with your "I lean slightly towards WCF" too :-) Should be fairly easy to spread the service as such out onto several web servers to provide failover protection.

Comment: *One disadvantage of WCF that you forgot is that it does add some processing overhead because it must serialize and deserialze messages.* - yes, but at the same time, it also provides a more decoupled system, giving you more flexibility in the long run

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, I agree, and that was what I was trying to say, although you can also make systems with pretty low coupling without WCF :)